# myUseHook is not functioning

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ant-design-pro, usehooks-ts

I created a useHook in a nextjs project that controls how my alert works. This is the hook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useAlert = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  console.log(isVisible)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Show the alert
    setIsVisible(true);
    
    // Hide the alert after a delay (e.g., 5 seconds)
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }, 5000); 

    // Cleanup the timeout on unmount
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  // Close Alert by button
  const closeAlert = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
    console.log("121212")
  };

  return { isVisible, closeAlert };
};

export default useAlert;
```

This is my alert component using ant design

```
import { CloseIcon } from "./icons/icon";
import { message } from "antd";
import useAlert from "../../useHooks/useAlert";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Alert = ({ alertText, success }) => {
  const { isVisible, closeAlert } = useAlert();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible) {
      // Show the success or error message using Ant Design's message component
      if (success) {
        message.success(alertText);
      } else {
        message.error(alertText);
      }
    }
  }, [isVisible, success, alertText]);

  // Render the alert message
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{alertText}</p>
      <button onClick={closeAlert}> <CloseIcon /> </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

But when i called it in my header, it does not render at all, but if i console.log in the function from where i called it, it logs
This is the component from which i called, the function is the "checkAccess" function

```
const HeaderTop = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const axiosPrivate = useAxiosPrivate();
  const profileUpdated = useProfileUpdate();
  const [openLogin, setLogin] = useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn] = useLoggedIn();
  const [LogOut] = Logout();
  const [SearchString, setSearchString] = useState('');
  const [isMobileCategories, setIsMobileCategories] = useState(false);
  const [catid, setCatid] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');
  const [errorAlert, setErrorAlert] = useState('');
  const [unReadMsgCount, setUnReadMsgCount] = useState(0);

  // User API
  const { user, userLoading, userError } = useUser();

  //category api
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(
    ['TopCategories'],
    api.getCategories
  );

  const CategoryData = data?.categories;

  // const newArr = CategoryData?.map((datas, i) => {
  //   setCatid(datas.name);
  // });

  const {
    data: dataCount,
    isLoading: isLoadingCount,
    isFetching: isFetchingCount,
    error: errorCount,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['Category Product Count', catid],
    queryFn: () => api.getCategoryProductCount(catid),
  });

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setLogin(true);
  };
  // const searchData = data?.productList;

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    router.push(`/search/${SearchString}`);
  };

  const [popOver, setPopOver] = useState(false);
  const handlePopOver = (e) => {
    setPopOver((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const sellFunction = () => {
    router.push('/add-product');
  };

  const checkAccess = () => {
    if (isLoggedIn && profileUpdated) {
      // setErrorAlert('Update your profile');
      sellFunction();
    } else {
      if(isLoggedIn){
        return (
          // <Alert alertText="Update your Profile" success={false} />
          message.error("Update your Profile")
        )
      } else {
        setLogin(true);
      }
      
    }
  };

  const [searchTab, setSearchTab] = useState(false);

  const profileData = [
    { name: 'Profile', link: `/profile/${user?._id}` },
    { name: 'Settings', link: '/profile/settings' },
    { name: 'Statistics', link: `/profile/${user?._id}?tab=statistics` },
  ];

  // /////////////// Get User favorite product and add color
  const {
    isLoading: myFavIsLoading,
    error: myFavError,
    data: myFavData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['Favorite Products Counts'],
    queryFn: () => axiosPrivate.get('/favorite'),
  });
  const noFavoriteProducts = myFavData?.data?.userfavorite;
  // const favoriteProdLength = 10;
  const isFavProductLength = noFavoriteProducts?.length != 0;

  // list of all user chat to display unread msg
  const userChatMsgCount = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['chat unread msg'],
    queryFn: async () => await axiosPrivate.get('/chat'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const chatList = userChatMsgCount?.data?.data?.chats;
    const unReadCount = chatList
      ?.map((item) => item?.unreadMessagesCount)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    setUnReadMsgCount(unReadCount);
  }, [userChatMsgCount]);

  return (
    <>
      {openLogin && <Auth setLogin={setLogin} />}
      <div className="grid grid-cols-[auto_1fr_auto] gap-5 items-center md:grid-cols-[1fr_auto] md:gap-10 py-1">
        {searchTab && <SearchTab setSearchTab={setSearchTab} />}
        <div className="flex w-max items-center md:hidden">
          <GrMenu
            className="text-3xl mr-3 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => {
              setIsMobileCategories(!isMobileCategories);
            }}
          />
          <CiSearch
            className="text-3xl text-jdgray-10 cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => setSearchTab(!searchTab)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="grid justify-center items-center max-w-2xl md:grid-cols-[auto_1fr]">
          <Links Jdref="/">
            <div className="w-32 h-10 relative">
              <Image src={Logo} layout="fill" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
          </Links>
          <div className="grid-cols-[1fr_auto] gap-6 ml-5 hidden md:grid">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <IconInput
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setSearchString(e.target.value);
                }}
                placeholder="Search"
                icon={<SearchIcon className="text-xl -mr-2" />}
                className="w-full h-full placeholder:text-[#828282]"
              />
            </form>
            <UserLocation />
          </div>
          {/* <div
              className={clsx([
                isFetching || data
                  ? "hidden absolute left-11 top-9 rounded p-2 bg-gray-200 w-[360px]"
                  : "hidden",
              ])}
            >
              {isFetching ? (
                <div>Loading....</div>
              ) : (
                searchData?.map((data) => (
                  <div className="w-full mt-3">
                    <Link href="/product/[slug]" as={`/product/${data?.slug}`}>
                      <a className="">{data?.name}</a>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                ))
              )}
            </div> */}
        </div>
        {!isLoggedIn ? (
          <div className="flex">
            <div className="flex">
              <Button
                onClick={handleLogin}
                size="md"
                rounded={true}
                outline="primary"
              >
                Login
              </Button>
              <Button
                size="md"
                rounded={true}
                color="primary"
                onClick={() => {
                  checkAccess();
                }}
                className="ml-5 hidden sm:flex"
              >
                Sell
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className="text-2xl text-[#4F4F4F] grid grid-cols-[repeat(4,_auto)] items-center md:gap-2 lg:gap-3 gap-2">
              <Links Jdref="/likes">
                {/* <FavoriteIcon /> */}
                {isFavProductLength ? (
                  <FavoriteIconFill className="text-primary" />
                ) : (
                  <FavoriteIcon />
                )}
              </Links>
              <Links Jdref="/chat" className="relative">
                <NewMessageIcon className="text-[27px] ml-1" />
                {unReadMsgCount > 0 && (
                  <span className="w-4 h-4 rounded-full bg-primary absolute -top-1 right-0 text-[10px] grid place-content-center text-white">
                    {unReadMsgCount > 99 ? 99 : unReadMsgCount}
                  </span>
                )}
              </Links>
              <div className="relative">
                <div
                  onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                  className="flex items-center"
                >
                  {user?.profilePicture ? (
                    <span className="w-[32px] h-[32px] border-2 border-primary rounded-full cursor-pointer">
                      <Image
                        src={user?.profilePicture}
                        width={32}
                        height={32}
                        alt="profile picture"
                        className="object-cover rounded-full"
                      />
                    </span>
                  ) : (
                    <UserCircleIcon className="text-[32px] hover:text-primary cursor-pointer" />
                  )}
                </div>
                {open && (
                  <div className="absolute top-5 right-0 mt-6 rounded w-[120px] z-20 shadow-xl">
                    {!userLoading ? (
                      <ul
                        className={`bg-white rounded-md shadow-[0_0_20px_-5px_rgba(0,0,0,0.3)] overflow-hidden grid`}
                      >
                        {profileData?.map((status, idx) => (
                          <Links key={idx} Jdref={status.link}>
                            <li
                              className={`w-full px-3 py-0.5 text-[15px] text-start hover:bg-primary hover:text-white cursor-pointer border-b border-neutral-200`}
                              onClick={() => {
                                if (status.name !== selected) {
                                  setSelected();
                                  setOpen(!open);
                                }
                              }}
                            >
                              {status.name}
                            </li>
                          </Links>
                        ))}
                        <HeadwayWidget />
                        <button
                          className={`w-full px-3 pb-0.5 pt-0 text-[15px] hover:bg-primary hover:text-white cursor-pointer text-start`}
                          onClick={() => LogOut()}
                        >
                          Logout
                        </button>
                      </ul>
                    ) : (
                      <span className="flex justify-center items-center absolute w-[120px] h-[120px] z-20 cursor-pointer bg-white mt-2 ">
                        <SpinLoading size="10" />
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
              <Button
                size="md"
                rounded={true}
                color="primary"
                onClick={() => {
                  checkAccess();
                }}
                className="hidden xs:block"
              >
                Sell
              </Button>
              {/* {errorAlert && (
              // <span className="fixed right-0 top-14 bg-red-500 text-white z-50">
              //   {errorAlert}
              // </span>
              // <Alert success={true} />
              message.error("Update you profile!")
            )} */}
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>

      {/* Mobile */}
      <div className="grid grid-cols-[auto_1fr] gap-5 items-center layout md:hidden">
        {isMobileCategories && (
          <MobileCategories
            isMobileCategories={isMobileCategories}
            setIsMobileCategories={setIsMobileCategories}
            schema={CategoryData ?? []}
            categoryID={setCatid}
            checkAccess={checkAccess}
            isLoading={isLoading}
          />
        )}
      </div>

      {router.asPath === '/' ? (
        <div className="fixed bottom-3 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 sm:hidden">
          <Button
            rounded={true}
            color="primary"
            size="md"
            onClick={() => {
              checkAccess();
            }}
            // className="rounded-full py-3 px-5 text-[15px]"
            className="flex items-center rounded-full py-3 text-[16px]"
          >
            <PlusIcon className="text-white mr-[1.6px]" /> Sell
          </Button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default HeaderTop;
```

i tried

```
const checkAccess = () => {
    if (isLoggedIn && profileUpdated) {
      // setErrorAlert('Update your profile');
      sellFunction();
    } else {
      if(isLoggedIn){
        return (
          <Alert alertText="Update your Profile" success={false} />
        )
      } else {
        setLogin(true);
      }
      
    }
  };
```

I expect it to pop-in an ant design that says "update profile" but now it is just blank

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `checkAccess` implementation. When you return the `Alert` component, it doesn't get mounted into the DOM.

Instead of returning the `Alert`, what you could do is either:

1. Create a React Portal with the `Alert`
2. Create state that is responsible for the displaying of the alert.

I'd go with the second option, as it's simplier:

```
const checkAccess = () => {
    if (isLoggedIn && profileUpdated) {
      // setErrorAlert('Update your profile');
      sellFunction();
    } else {
      if(isLoggedIn){
        setShowAlert(true);
    } else {
        setLogin(true);
      }
      
    }
  };

// return statement
...
{showAlert && <Alert alertText="Update your Profile" success={false} onTimeout={() => setShowAlert(false)} />
```

Notice the addition of `onTimeout` prop which should be called inside the `Alert`, otherwise you'd have to add another `useEffect` that handles the closing of the alert. Also, I'd delegate logic of handling `Alert` state (show/hide) to parent component, it would simplify the code and make it much easier to understand and work with.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, ill go through with htis